# Refresh hud in libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

My hud looks like this. The picture in the middle is supposed to display the current weapon of the player. I added the image with the following code:

```java
table.add(weaponImage).width(weaponWidth).height(weaponHeight);
```

[image]

In my hud, I made a method called "updateWeapon" to change the image, which didn't work.

```java
public void changeSword(String swordName) {
        weaponImage = new Image(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(swordName)));
        System.out.println("Weapon changed");
    }
```

"Weapon changed" gets printed out in the console, but the image doesn't change.
**I think that's because the hud doesn't get refreshed, so how do I do that?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are changing the reference of an already assigned reference (or pointer if you like).

Say that the original weaponImage is at `0x1` address. The table is instructed to display whatever is at `0x1`. Now later you change the weaponImage pointer to a new image at `0x5`, but the table took the first value.

To update the image you need to work with the original `0x1` address and switch the image there.

Change

```
weaponImage = new Image(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(swordName)));
```

to

```
weaponImage.setDrawable(new TextureRegionDrawable(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(swordName)));
```

But grab that texture first you don't want to do a `new` everytime.